# Send a uint8array to browser

Tags: javascript, blob, createobjecturl, pdf-lib.js

I am using the package hopding/pdf-lib from github within the browser to generate a pdf. I get the result as a uint8array. I can send this to the browser using rndme/download from github which stores the pdf first to the local disk and then sends it to a new browser tab and opens it in the pdf viewer. As I dont want to store it to disk i tried the following code:

```
    const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();  // create the pdf as uint8array
    //download(pdfBytes, fn, "application/pdf");
    let blb = new Blob(pdfBytes, {type: 'application/pdf'});
    let link = window.URL.createObjectURL(blb);
    window.open(link);
```

This opens the new tab with the pdf viewer, however it is empty. I checked the blob with the debugger and it tells me:

Blob { size: 772729, type: "application/pdf" }

There are no error messages. Why is the target empty?

Answer (score 1):

The `pdfBytes` should be passed into the blob constructor in an array. The first argument of the [blob constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) should be an array containing all the objects to be inserted into the blob.

An error is not being thrown because `pdfBytes` is an array of numbers, so all the numbers in the array are being inserted into the blob, rather than `pdfBytes` itself.

The blob creation should look like this:

```js
let blb = new Blob([ pdfBytes ], {type: 'application/pdf'})
// notice how pdfBytes is passed inside of an array
```